# Calling function delete worksheet issue

Tags: vba

I assumed that this would be relatively straight forward however I'm getting an error.

Error: `Object doesn't support this property or method`

**My code:**

```
    '*************************************************************
    '       Delete existing sheets to start reset the program
    '*************************************************************
    Dim wsPivot As Worksheet
    Set wsPivot = Worksheets("UA.01.01 Breakdown per Product")
    wsPivot.Select
    deleteSheetFunc (wsPivot)
```

*Function*

```
Function deleteSheetFunc(ws As Worksheet)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True        

End Function
```

I'm at a loss where I'm going wrong. Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually to use `deleteSheetFunc` you can't just do:

```
deleteSheetFunc(wsPivot)
```

but you have to use `Call`:

```
Call deleteSheetFunc(wsPivot)
```

**Or**

You have to call your function that way:

```
deleteSheetFunc wsPivot
```

I don't know why you have to use it like that but now I remember I had the same error once.
Personnaly I like using `Call` because it's explicit that you call something.

*Note* You could have used `Sub` instead of `Function` since you have no return value

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, what determines whether you use "Call"

Comment: No prob, I had that error when using `MsgBox` with multiple parameters (Using `()` and no `Call`), and it took me a long time to figure out what didn't worked (Didn't found what I needed on the web actually)